# Stacked cumulative histograms/area plot with R

Tags: r, histogram, stacked-area-chart

I have some data which looks like

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.table( sample(1:6,1000,replace=T), rnorm(1000, mean = 5))
     V1       V2
   1:  2 5.077303
   2:  3 4.703131
   3:  4 3.816758
   4:  6 5.011293
   5:  2 5.991601
  ---            
 996:  5 5.114406
 997:  4 4.607735
 998:  2 6.652358
 999:  2 3.756302
1000:  2 4.088074
```

I want to create a plot with some sort of cumulative histograms or cumulative area graph filled by V1 and with V2 on the x-axis, stacked on top of each other. The result should look something like this:

[http://i.imgur.com/GGywhzu.png](https://i.imgur.com/GGywhzu.png)

This is what I tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(group=V1, x = V2, fill=as.factor(V1))) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)/sum(..counts..)), bins = 50)
```

However it does not stack the data correctly onto each other. It would also be nicer with an area plot, instead of the histogram bars. This is what the above code produces:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYswP.png)

Comment: When using `sample()`, use `set.seed()` so your data is reproducible. Also best to avoid unnecessary dependencies in your sample like `data.table` when a simple `data.frame` would probably work just fine. What exactly do you want on the x and y axes for your example. I assume you've at least made some attempt to draw this. Share the code you tried and describe where exactly you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thank you, I added some details, I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

is that what you're looking for?

```
data$V1 <- as.factor(data$V1)
ggplot(data,aes(group=V1,fill=V1,x=V2))+
  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Yes it goes in the right direction, but I still have some issues left (see edit)